# Is the .ttf format on Android the standard ttf format?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, fonts, android-wear, emoticons

I have an quite old smartwatch (LG W100) with only Android Wear 1.5.0 (Marshmallow) on it. Because my phone is a lot newer, I wanted to replace the NotoColorEmoji.ttf with a newer version from the Google website.
But when I replaced the file in the /system/fonts folder, no Emojis at all were displayed anymore.
When instead I took the ttf file from my Phone and put it on the watch it worked.
So what is the actual difference between those file?